# Issues when running vagrant in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, ubuntu-14.04

When running vagrant with latest package of `Ubuntu 14.04`, I got the following error message. Is there any configuration for Virtualbox? The provider is Virtualbox, and not special configuration after `apt-get install virtualbox`. BTW, can not connect to this host by GUI :(.

```
# vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'ubuntu/trusty64' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it
to boot. Valid states are 'starting, running'. The machine is in the
'poweroff' state. Please verify everything is configured
properly and try again.

If the provider you're using has a GUI that comes with it,
it is often helpful to open that and watch the machine, since the
GUI often has more helpful error messages than Vagrant can retrieve.
For example, if you're using VirtualBox, run `vagrant up` while the
VirtualBox GUI is open.

The primary issue for this error is that the provider you're using
is not properly configured. This is very rarely a Vagrant issue.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable `VT-x` Virtualization Technology in `BIOS` and still your problem remains see issue [vagrant issues 2157](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/2157) and this [issue](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/bosh-lite/issues/220).